# Error on run of NoraUi DEMO with Internet Explorer

Tags: iedriverserver, noraui

When I run by Chrome or PhantomJs the NoraUi DEMO is OK but by Internet explorer, I have this error:

```
[2017-06-08 10:34:02]: HTML title Exception
org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for condition to not be valid: title to be "". Current title: "" (tried for 20 second(s) with 500 MILLISECONDS interval)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait.timeoutException(WebDriverWait.java:80)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:232)
    at noraui.utils.Context.waitUntil(Context.java:426)
    at noraui.application.page.demo.DemoPage.checkPage(DemoPage.java:43)
    at noraui.application.steps.demo.HelloByeSteps.checkDemoPortalPage(HelloByeSteps.java:44)
    at noraui.application.steps.demo.HelloByeSteps$$EnhancerByGuice$$35e140d9.CGLIB$checkDemoPortalPage$6(<generated>)
    at noraui.application.steps.demo.HelloByeSteps$$EnhancerByGuice$$35e140d9$$FastClassByGuice$$928eba72.invoke(<generated>)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.proxy.$MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InterceptorStackCallback$InterceptedMethodInvocation.proceed(InterceptorStackCallback.java:75)
    at noraui.cucumber.interceptor.StepInterceptor.invoke(StepInterceptor.java:63)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InterceptorStackCallback$InterceptedMethodInvocation.proceed(InterceptorStackCallback.java:75)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InterceptorStackCallback.intercept(InterceptorStackCallback.java:55)
    at noraui.application.steps.demo.HelloByeSteps$$EnhancerByGuice$$35e140d9.checkDemoPortalPage(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at cucumber.runtime.Utils$1.call(Utils.java:40)
    at cucumber.runtime.Timeout.timeout(Timeout.java:16)
    at cucumber.runtime.Utils.invoke(Utils.java:34)
    at cucumber.runtime.java.JavaStepDefinition.execute(JavaStepDefinition.java:38)
    at cucumber.runtime.StepDefinitionMatch.runStep(StepDefinitionMatch.java:48)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.runStep(Runtime.java:300)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.StepContainer.runStep(StepContainer.java:44)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.StepContainer.runSteps(StepContainer.java:39)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberScenario.run(CucumberScenario.java:44)
    at cucumber.runtime.junit.ExecutionUnitRunner.run(ExecutionUnitRunner.java:102)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at cucumber.runtime.junit.ExamplesRunner.run(ExamplesRunner.java:59)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at cucumber.runtime.junit.ScenarioOutlineRunner.run(ScenarioOutlineRunner.java:53)
    at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.runChild(FeatureRunner.java:63)
    at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.runChild(FeatureRunner.java:18)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.run(FeatureRunner.java:70)
    at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.runChild(Cucumber.java:95)
    at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.runChild(Cucumber.java:38)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.run(Cucumber.java:100)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:367)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeWithRerun(JUnit4Provider.java:274)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:238)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:290)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:242)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:121)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchWindowException: Unable to get browser (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 17 milliseconds
Build info: version: '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'ITEM-72885', ip: '192.168.56.1', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_66'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver
Capabilities [{se:ieOptions={browserAttachTimeout=0, ie.enableFullPageScreenshot=true, enablePersistentHover=false, ie.forceCreateProcessApi=false, ie.forceShellWindowsApi=false, ignoreZoomSetting=true, ie.fileUploadDialogTimeout=3000, ie.useLegacyFileUploadDialogHandling=false, nativeEvents=true, ie.ensureCleanSession=true, elementScrollBehavior=0, ie.browserCommandLineSwitches=, requireWindowFocus=true, initialBrowserUrl=http://localhost:6546/, ignoreProtectedModeSettings=true, enableElementCacheCleanup=true}, browserName=internet explorer, pageLoadStrategy=normal, javascriptEnabled=true, version=11, platform=WINDOWS, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=accept}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going to Internet Options --> Security --> "Enable Protected Mode" on ALL zones should either be checked or ALL unchecked.

[image]