# Error using Selenium Chrome Webdriver with Java, Maven and Windows 10 - Access is Denied

Tags: java, selenium, maven, windows-10

```
Jan 13, 2021 8:29:16 AM org.openqa.selenium.os.OsProcess checkForError
SEVERE: org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Execution failed (Exit value: -559038737. Caused by java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "...\chromedriver.exe" (in directory "."): CreateProcess error=5, Access is denied)
```

When I attempt to run Selenium Webdriver on my Windows 10 machine using Maven, Google Chrome Browser and Java, I come across this message. I have checked the permissions and everything appears to be set up correctly:

[image][image]

What could be causing this Access denied issue?

EDIT: So that I can re-open this question, the above linked questions do NOT answer my problem, my problem is related to error code 5, Access Denied. (the linked questions appear to be related to Error code 1)
Here's my code to prove my statement:

```
psf Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(BrowserRunTime.class);
logger.info("*** Chrome Simulation(): default viewport");
String exePath = System.getProperty(USER_DIR) + "\\src\\main\\resources\\chromedriver.exe";
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", exePath);
ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.addArguments("--start-maximized");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);       
driver.get(browserMeta.getProperties().getProperty(DESKTOP_URL));
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
```

Comment: I am not understand all your problem but can you try this before please? https://stackoverflow.com/a/44430707/3535537

Comment: @StéphaneGRILLON - Not relevant - That's to solve IE problems, this is specifically linked to Chrome

Comment: oki, sorry. Can you try add this if (!new File(pathWebdriver).setExecutable(true)) {
            throw new TechnicalException(....);
        }  Cf. https://github.com/NoraUi/NoraUi/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/noraui/browser/DriverFactory.java

Comment: @StéphaneGRILLON - Okay. I tried that and when I ran it, the code stepped straight over the if, meaning it is executable

Comment: Question reoponed, mistakes happen sometimes, sorry for that

Comment: @DimaRostopira - thanks. Much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically, I managed to resolve the issue by restarting my PC, it just seemed to be a transient issue that resolves itself on a restart. If anyone has issues with Access Denied issues when you shouldn't; try restarting your PC first.